# Rewriting ParamSet ids from mlr3::paradox()

Tags: mlr3

Let's say I have the following `ParamSet` object:

```
my_ps = paradox::ps(
    minsplit = p_int(1, 64, logscale = TRUE),
    cp = p_dbl(1e-04, 1, logscale = TRUE))
```

Is it possible to rename `minsplit` to `survTree.minsplit` without changing anything else?

The reason for this is that I use some learners as part of a `GraphLearner` and so their parameters names changed and I would like to have some code that adds the `learner$id` in front the parameters to use later for tuning (rather than rewriting them from scratch with the new names)

Comment: Hey, sorry for the late response! I don't think that this is possible with the current API without using a somewhat hacky solution. I am also not sure whether it can be easily implemented.

Comment: I did try to hack it I remember from a `data.table` form but later some ids didn't match during `AutoTuner`-ing so I totally get that!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I have a partial solution here. It is only partial, because it does not support the transformation.

Where it works:

```r
library(paradox)

my_ps = paradox::ps(
  minsplit = p_int(1, 64),
  cp = p_dbl(1e-04, 1)
)

my_ps$set_id = "john"

my_psc = ParamSetCollection$new(list(my_ps))

print(my_psc)
#> <ParamSetCollection>
#>               id    class lower upper nlevels        default value
#> 1: john.minsplit ParamInt 1e+00    64      64 <NoDefault[3]>      
#> 2:       john.cp ParamDbl 1e-04     1     Inf <NoDefault[3]>
```

<sup>Created on 2022-12-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Where it does not:

```r
library(paradox)

my_ps = paradox::ps(
  minsplit = p_int(1, 64, logscale = TRUE),
  cp = p_dbl(1e-04, 1)
)

my_ps$set_id = "john"

my_psc = ParamSetCollection$new(list(my_ps))
#> Error in .__ParamSetCollection__initialize(self = self, private = private, : Building a collection out sets, where a ParamSet has a trafo is currently unsupported!
```

<sup>Created on 2022-12-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

The underlying problem is that we did not solve the problem of how to reconcile the parameter transformations of individual ParamSets and a possible parameter transformation of the `ParamSetCollection`

I fear that there is currently no neat solution for your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry I can not comment yet, this is not exactly the solution you are looking for but I hope this will fix the problem you are having.

You can set the `param_space` in the learner, before putting it in the graph, i.e. sticking with your search space. After you create the `GraphLearner` regularly it will have the desired search space.

A concrete example:

```r
library(mlr3verse)

learner = lrn("regr.rpart", cp = to_tune(0.1, 0.2))

glrn = as_learner(po("pca") %>>% po("learner", learner))

at = auto_tuner(
  "random_search",
  glrn,
  rsmp("holdout"),
  term_evals = 10
)

task = tsk("mtcars")

at$train(task)
```

Comment: Hi Lukas, yes that would work! But is it possible? I tried to set `ps = ps(lambda = p_dbl(1e-03, 10, logscale = TRUE))` to the model `coxnet = lrn('surv.glmnet', id = 'CoxNet')` but couldn't do it - e.g. `coxnet$param_set` is read-only. Is there any other way?

Comment: I think what he meant by that is that you can first set the parameters with the `to_tune()` token in for the learner and when you then wrap the learner in the graph learner, the graph learner will understand how to tone the parameters of the learner

Comment: The problem I can't have that solution, since I want to have the parameter spaces seperately (more modular) and second some of these can't be written with `to_tune()` or would be very hard to (i.e. see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73527213/setting-early-stopping-rounds-in-xgboost-learner-using-mlr3 answer of yours :)